# Copying files up or down

Tags: networking, web-server, copy

Considering two file servers which use most of their bandwidth to send files to clients on the worldwide interwebs. Every now and then Server 1 needs to store one of his files on Server 2, they both are connected to the same local area network.

Should the current file owner (Server 1) either:

1. **Upload** the file to Server 2
2. Tell Server 2 to **download** the file from him

I'm curious what the advantages and disadvantages of both ways are.

Answer (score 2):

If the servers are indeed on the same LAN, upload vs download is a misnomer here because when you flip the sender and receiver, it's essentially the same operation. These terms are irrelevant because they will be identical in terms of bandwidth. The net result is that the bytes of the file still have to be transferred from source to destination, in this case, Server 1 to Server 2, on either approach.

If you're looking for a pro vs con on the approach to solving the problem, there are too many variables and too few facts about the servers/OS/etc here to suggest a solution, so just do whatever you are comfortable scripting.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the lightest approach, when and from where do you know you have to send the file.
If it is just a daily move you could flip coins, but if server 1 knows fist it has to do someting with server 2 let it do the push or pull.